# Hide or replace Standard button in Record Edit page

Tags: visualforce, community, custom-button

I have a requirement in cases. I have record type called VARMA, and we have a standard button called "Save & Edit" so, whenever support rep click this button we need to validate subject could not be null.

So, I created a custom button and I am able to display only record detail page, but I am unable to hide the standard button from record edit page.

And my custom button is working fine. Is there any possibility to hide or replace standard button with my custom button for this particular record type, other than VF page?

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled with a validation rule on `Case` object instead of a custom button. The following validation rule formula should work in your case:

```
AND( 
$RecordType.Name = "VARMA", 
ISBLANK(Subject))
```

This will prevent a user from saving a Case record if the `Record Type` is *VARMA* and `Subject` field is empty or null.

---

Also, to answer your question:

You can't replace *standard* with *custom* buttons on object's **edit page** (without creating a custom VF page). There's an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrMWAA0) for this feature, so you can go to that link and vote for it.